# How to diagnose insertion point/trackpad jitters?

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad, cursor

When I’m typing in any application (e.g. Chrome, Safari, MS Word, Evernote), the insertion point often jumps around unexpectedly. I have this problem with the builtin trackpad and my magic trackpad at home. *Caveat Since this is both a disease of the internal trackpad and the magic trackpad then it can't be the cable between the internal trackpad and the motherboard*

My MBP has been for service once, I believe they changed a cable between the trackpad and motherboard. No dice. I have wiped the OS and reinstalled from scratch. I have booted in safe mode. You get the idea. I'm certain that most of the time I'm nowhere near the trackpad when it happens. (Like 10 seconds ago).

Is this hardware? Software? I must admit I don’t have a clue how to diagnose. My leaning is likely software.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
OS 10.12.5 (although this has been going on for over a year)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you've read [Apple's support documentation on this issue](https://support.apple.com/en-kw/HT203171) by now and have had no luck.

Since the issue wasn't resolved even after reinstalling macOS from scratch and booting into safe mode, this should definitely be a hardware problem. Your trackpad is slowly dying. The connector is probably loose or getting old. Since you say that the trackpad cable has already been changed once, it probably wasn't serviced properly the first time.

The best thing to do here would be to go back to an Apple service center and get your laptop checked again. That's almost always the best route to take in case of hardware problems with Apple products.

FYI: There are people who've said that a [firm slap with the palm of their hand fixed their trackpad issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90284/159129). Try at your own risk though.

Comment: Sorry as much as I would like to say this is it, there is an important detail I forgot that should rule this out. My Magic Trackpad (removeable battery) suffers the same problem and this would bypass the internal cables. This leans to towards a software problem.

Comment: @MarkLevison given that the internal trackpad remains active while you use the external one, it can still throw the cursor off if hardware issues make it feel "ghost" touch events.

Comment: @MarkLevison Maybe try disabling your internal trackpad and use the external one?

Comment: @AndréBorie and Daksh Shah (sorry I can't notify) I've in the past tried disabling the internal trackpad when the external one is available. No difference.

Comment: I just ordered a new Magic Trackpad to see if that makes a meaningful difference.

Comment: Strangely in the days since I started using a Magic Trackpad 2 I've had fewer if any issues. I've been on vacation for the past month so very little computer use. The next few weeks will be telling.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that appeared when Sierra was new, and it rendered my MacCook Pro unusable. Weary of trying fix after fix from the web, I finally did an Internet Reinstall...and when that didn't work, did a second.

Result: fixed.

One could also do a clean IR, bet that would be even faster.

Astonished to discover this problem had been around in previous OS versions. 
But I do know the "fix".